# Cancel or Delete Scheduled Job - HangFire

Tags: c#, asp.net, job-scheduling, hangfire

I have scheduled a Job via using Hangfire library. My scheduled Code like below.

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => MyRepository.SomeMethod(2),TimeSpan.FromDays(7));

public static bool DownGradeUserPlan(int userId)
    {
        //Write logic here
    }
```

Now I want to Delete this Scheduled Job later on some event.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`BackgroundJob.Schedule` returns you an id of that job, you can use it to delete this job:

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(() =>  MyRepository.SomeMethod(2),TimeSpan.FromDays(7));

BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId);
```

Comment: For this I need to save the JobId in database so I can use that later when needed.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to save their IDs to retrieve the jobs later. Instead, you can utilize the *MonitoringApi* class of the Hangfire API. Note that, you will need to filter out the jobs according to your needs.

*Text* is my custom class in my example code.

```
public void ProcessInBackground(Text text)
{
    // Some code
}

public void SomeMethod(Text text)
{
    // Some code

    // Delete existing jobs before adding a new one
    DeleteExistingJobs(text.TextId);

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ProcessInBackground(text));
}

private void DeleteExistingJobs(int textId)
{
    var monitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

    var jobsProcessing = monitor.ProcessingJobs(0, int.MaxValue)
        .Where(x => x.Value.Job.Method.Name == "ProcessInBackground");
    foreach (var j in jobsProcessing)
    {
        var t = (Text)j.Value.Job.Args[0];
        if (t.TextId == textId)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Delete(j.Key);
        }
    }

    var jobsScheduled = monitor.ScheduledJobs(0, int.MaxValue)
        .Where(x => x.Value.Job.Method.Name == "ProcessInBackground");
    foreach (var j in jobsScheduled)
    {
        var t = (Text)j.Value.Job.Args[0];
        if (t.TextId == textId)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Delete(j.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

My reference: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/cancel-a-running-job/603/10

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this, however, if its automated, you will not know what the ID is in the "DeleteExistingJobs" is, unless you look in the Hangfire UI.